# cannot be used as a JSX component. Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.ts(2786)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jsx, tsx

I got this code:

```
    function searchData(searchWord: any) {
        if (originalData.length > 0) {
            if (searchWord !== "") {
                setDataList([...originalData.filter((svc: any) => 
                removeAccent(svc.name.toLowerCase())
                .includes(removeAccent(searchWord.toLowerCase()))),]);
            } else {
                setDataList([...originalData]);
            }
        }
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar currentUser={props.currentUser} setCurrentUser={props.setCurrentUser} />
            <div style={{ paddingTop: "80px", marginBottom: "3rem", minHeight: "90vh" }}>
                <div className="text-center header">
                    <h1 className="title">Tu agente de reserva personal</h1>
                    <h4 className="title">Consulta servicios y agenda citas en línea</h4>
                </div>
                <Row className="justify-content-center text-center mt-5">
                    <Col xs="11" sm="8" md="7" lg="6" xl="5">
                        <h1 className="title">Nuestros prestadores de servicios. </h1>
                        <FormControl onChange={e => searchData(e.target.value)}/>                  
                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <CardList data={dataList}></CardList>
            </div>
            <Footer />
        </div>
    )
}
```

And it returns me this:

"'Navbar' cannot be used as a JSX component."

"Its return type 'void' is not a valid JSX element.ts(2786)"

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have an extra brace before return.

Answer (score 1):

As Antonio rightly pointed out, the issue is a spare closing bracket before returning the JSX.

This is equivalent to returning undefined, which is not valid JSX for React, hence the error message.

To find those issues it is a good idea to autoformat your code, either using an autoformatter like Prettier, or by triggering an Autoformat on demand. Here is how you can do it in VSCode:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> (MacOS) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command box, then type *"Format Document"*

Or use the direct shortcut <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

This assumes VSCode found out the right language of your file (which is usually done based on the file extension).